# Why I am not been able to close any question? 

Tags: support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Once I got close link in questions after getting enough rep on Stack Overflow but once I voted a question to close it and the link is gone forever. Now I never seen close link below any question Why?

**Edit**

Its my mistake I have seen some times the link below some questions during my question may be and i try to click on it and vote for close so I post question here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At your reputation level, you can only see the vote-to-close dialog on your *own* questions. You don't get the privilege for all questions until you reach 3,000.